# PostGIS: how to split a polyline into straight segments?

Tags: postgis, line, postgis-2.0, splitting

I'm working with PostGIS 2.1.8. I need to split a polyline into as many straight segments this polyline contains. Here is an illustration to make it clear enough:

[image: Polyline to segments]

The initial feature is only one row and the query should produce a 4 rows result with attributes values being maintained and geometry column changed (I don't want to update `length` column):

```
# Initial table:

id   | name    | length   | the_geom
-----+---------+----------+-----------------
1    | Line 1  | 12.2     | 01000111100000


# Result table:

id   | name    | length   | the_geom
-----+---------+----------+-----------------
1    | Line 1  | 12.2     | 01000111100000
2    | Line 1  | 12.2     | 01001111000011
3    | Line 1  | 12.2     | 01000110010000
4    | Line 1  | 12.2     | 00000111100000
```

I have found the function `st_subdivide()` ([see here](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html)) but it is available from PostGIS version 2.2... I can't upgrade my PostGIS version because I'm at work and not allowed to do it.

Any idea on how to achieve that with an older than 2.2 PostGIS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user30184 comment, I found the following solution:

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  length,
  the_geom

FROM (SELECT
  id,
  name,
  length,
  (st_dump(the_geom)).geom AS the_geom
);
```